# Stateless Factory with EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have a requirement to get pdf documents from my system. I'm using Apache Fop for this - and this library is using 2 files to generate pdf - xsl file with structure and styling and xml with data. So I'm getting xsl file from web resources, but now I need to generate xml with data from database. I tried this solution:
I have this interface:

```
public interface PrintableDocument {
    Object getJaxBOjbect(Long personId);
}
```

That's one of the stateless bean to get object, I need 10 more beans like this to get different data for different documents.

```
@Stateless
@PrintableDocumentOneQualifier
public class PrintableDocumentOne implements PrintableDocument {

    @Inject
    private SomeRepository repository;

    public Object getJaxBOjbect(Long personId) {
    // Getting information from database
    // formulating Object with data and returning it
    }
}
```

So now I want to create Factory like this one:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PrintableDocumentsFactory {

    @Inject
    @PrintableDocumentOneQualifier
    private PrintableDocument printableDocumentOne;

    @Inject
    @PrintableDocumentTwoQualifier
    private PrintableDocument printableDocumentTwo;

    private Map<String, PrintableDocument> map = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        map.put("one", printableDocumentOne);
        map.put("two", printableDocumentTwo);
    }

    public PrintableDocument getPrintableDocument(String type) {
        return map.get(type);
    }

}
```

And on the service bean I want to use this factory:

```
@Stateless
@Local(DocumentService.class)
public class DocumentServiceBean {

    @Inject
    private PrintableDocumentsFactory factory;

    public byte[] getPdf(InputStream xsl, Long id, String type) {
        PrintableDocument printableDocument = 
             factory.getPrintableDocument(type);
        Object jaxBOject = printableDocument.getJaxBObject(id);
        //Use this object to get pdf and return it to web controller.
    }

}
```

But now I'm getting null from getPrintableDocument from factory. I think the problem is that I need stateless beans, and they are getting picked back to EJB container, when getPrintableDocument method ends. So my question is: how can I manage this kind of situation?

**EDIT 1:** Missed PostConstruct annotation on init in Factory. Fixed that, still have the problem.

**EDIT 2:** If I will have `@Singleton` on my Factory will it hold just one by one instances of stateless `PrintableDocument` beans or it will return pooled instances instead? Because now I have to refill strategy holder map on factory when system will need another been to answer the request.

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` file? If so can you share it? In addition, can you specify what container you're deploying to?

Comment: @JohnAment beans.xml is empty as i don't have any interceptors, alternatives and so on. Container - Wildfly 10.1.0.Final. Actually this solution is working now even with `@Inject` annotation. I wonder if some other problem was related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `@EJB` instead of `@Inject` to inject the `PrintableDocumentsFactory` into your `DocumentServiceBean`.

Comment: I want specifically use `@Inject` because I have unit tests with CDI alternatives with arquillian. Thanks in advance, will try it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `@PostConstruct` annotation to `PrintableDocumentsFactory.init()` method. Currently the `init` method won't be called, so no get registered in the map.

Comment: Actually I missed that annotation on listing. I have it on project. Sorry, my bad. Will edit question.